# JNDI data source configuration issue in spring boot

Tags: jdbc, spring-boot, jdbctemplate, objectdatasource, tomcat-dbcp

**My java configuration file looks like below -**

```
@Bean
public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate() {
    JdbcTemplate template = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource());
    return template;
}

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    JndiDataSourceLookup dataSource = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
    return dataSource.getDataSource(env.getProperty("spring.datasource"));
}
```

**My property file properties looks like below -**

```
spring.datasource.username=<myusername>
spring.datasource.password=<mypassword>
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@<url>
spring.datasource.driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
spring.datasource.initSQL=select 1 from dual
spring.datasource.maxActive=50
spring.datasource.minIdle=20
spring.datasource.maxIdle=50
spring.datasource.defaultAutoCommit=true
spring.datasource.initialSize=20
spring.datasource.maxWait=300000
spring.datasource.validationQuery=select 1 from dual
spring.datasource.testOnBorrow=true
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle=false
spring.datasource.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=-1
spring.datasource.testOnReturn=false
spring.datasource.poolPreparedStatements=true
```

**In the place i'm autowiring JdbcTemplate, in one of the method, I try printing jdbcTemplate.getDataSource() and it prints the following -**

```
org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource@659c54d2{ConnectionPool[defaultAutoCommit=null; defaultReadOnly=null; defaultTransactionIsolation=-1; defaultCatalog=null; driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver; maxActive=100; maxIdle=100; minIdle=10; initialSize=10; maxWait=30000; testOnBorrow=true; testOnReturn=false; timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=5000; numTestsPerEvictionRun=0; minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=60000; testWhileIdle=false; testOnConnect=false; password=************; url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@<url>; username=<myusername>; validationQuery=SELECT 'Hello' from DUAL; validationQueryTimeout=-1; validatorClassName=null; validationInterval=30000; accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed=true; removeAbandoned=false; removeAbandonedTimeout=60; logAbandoned=false; connectionProperties=null; initSQL=null; jdbcInterceptors=null; jmxEnabled=true; fairQueue=true; useEquals=true; abandonWhenPercentageFull=0; maxAge=0; useLock=false; dataSource=null; dataSourceJNDI=null; suspectTimeout=0; alternateUsernameAllowed=false; commitOnReturn=false; rollbackOnReturn=false; useDisposableConnectionFacade=true; logValidationErrors=false; propagateInterruptState=false; ignoreExceptionOnPreLoad=false; }
```

It basically did not take any of the configuration I've setup except the username, password and the URL. Why is that?

Comment: Have you looked at the docs for [JndiDataSourceLookup](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/lookup/JndiDataSourceLookup.html)? Your config doesn't provide a `spring.datasource` property that resolves  to a JNDI name. It appears you might have `spring.datasource.jndi-name` somewhere (the default), as it isn't throwing an exception. If you're using JNDI, the datasource config is provided by your container, and your properties file isn't really needed. You don't need to explicitly provide the `DataSource` and `JdbcTemplate` beans..

Comment: Remove your beans, remove all your `spring.datasource` properties and only add a single `spring.datasource.jndi-name` property and restart your application. However do you really  need a JNDI lookup? When using an embedded tomcat it doesn't really add anything but complexity to your application.

Comment: How would i be able to configure the properties of the embedded tomcat's  datasource?